# Changing Text of each TAB in Tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

Here's what my TABS look like at the moment:

[image]

How would I change the text of the TextView I am using to display the text, for each individual TAB?

As you can see, the text of each TAB is the same. I have tried using methods of changing the text for each individual one, but nothing seems to work.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

XML using to display the TextView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Tab_Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/* Tab identifiers */
private final String TAB_A = "Appointments";
private final String TAB_B = "Calender";
private final String TAB_C = "Profile";
private final String TAB_D = "Settings";

private String selectedTab;

private static TabHost mTabHost;

private Fragment1 fragment1;
private Fragment2 fragment2;
private Fragment3 fragment3;
private Fragment4 fragment4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragment3 = new Fragment3();
    fragment4 = new Fragment4();

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(listener);
    mTabHost.setup();

    initializeTab();
}

// TABS



public void initializeTab() {
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_A);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    //First TAB

    spec.setIndicator(createTabView(TAB_A, R.drawable.tab1_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_B);



    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }

    });

    //Second TAB

    spec.setIndicator(createTabView(TAB_B, R.drawable.tab2_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_C);
    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    //Third TAB

    spec.setIndicator(createTabView(TAB_C, R.drawable.tab3_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_D);
    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    //Fourth TAB

    spec.setIndicator(createTabView("TAB_D", R.drawable.tab4_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    spec.setIndicator("Tab4");

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

TabHost.OnTabChangeListener listener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        /* Set current tab.. */
        if (tabId.equals(TAB_A)) {
            pushFragments(tabId, fragment1);
            selectedTab = TAB_A;
        } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_B)) {
            pushFragments(tabId, fragment2);
            selectedTab = TAB_B;
        } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_C)) {
            pushFragments(tabId, fragment3);
            selectedTab = TAB_C;
        } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_D)) {
            pushFragments(tabId, fragment4);
            selectedTab = TAB_D;
        }
    }
};

/*
 * adds the fragment to the FrameLayout
 */
public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

/*
 * returns the tab view i.e. the tab icon and text
 */
private View createTabView(final String tabText, final int id) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);

    //Tab image

    ImageView imageViewTabIcon = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    imageViewTabIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));

    //Tab text

    TextView TextViewTAB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tab_Text);



    return view;
}

public static void tabfresh() {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

public static void tabfresh_sal() {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
}
```

Crash LOG for @kalyan pvs

```
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.question.question/com.question.question.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at com.question.question.MainActivity.createTabView(MainActivity.java:165)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at com.question.question.MainActivity.initializeTab(MainActivity.java:70)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at com.question.question.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
11-04 11:29:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18623):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: private View createTabView(final String tabText, final int id), call this method with the tabText you would like to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextViewTAB.setText(tabText);`   //Added to your code

In this method set the text for the individual tabs

```
private View createTabView(final String tabText, final int id) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);

//Tab image

ImageView imageViewTabIcon = (ImageView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
imageViewTabIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));

//Tab text

TextView TextViewTAB = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.Tab_Text);  //Added to your code

TextViewTAB.setText(tabText);   //Added to your code

return view;
}
```

`tabText` which already passed as a paramenter in method

Comment: It crashes when using this code, I have updated my answer with the crash LOG.

Comment: TextView TextViewTAB = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.Tab_Text);
change like this line..view.findViewById added

Answer (score 0):

You are using TabHost, first of which its deprecated and still u want to use it change the extends part of you class with **TabActivity**

**EDIT**:

My Code with TabActivity Change it as per your requirement:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

/** The m tab host. */
private TabHost mTabHost;

/** The intent. */
Intent intent;

/** The feature. */
short feature = 1;

/** The deal. */
short deal = 2;

/** The bundle. */
Bundle bundle;

/** The my drawable. */
Drawable myDrawable;

/** The active fragment. */
public TabFragment activeFragment;

/** The add deal interface. */
AddDealInterface addDealInterface;

/** The link name. */
String linkName;

/**
 * Sets the adds the deal interface.
 * 
 * @param addDealInterface
 *            the new adds the deal interface
 */
public void setAddDealInterface(AddDealInterface addDealInterface) {
    this.addDealInterface = addDealInterface;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    String Language = getIntent().getStringExtra("lang");
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabclick1);
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putShort("Value", feature);
    bundle.putString("lang", Language);

    final Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, MainView.class);
    i.putExtra("bundle", bundle);

    TabSpec spec1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.featured));
    spec1.setContent(i);
    spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(getApplicationContext(), myDrawable,
            getString(R.string.featured)));

    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabclick2);
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putShort("Value", deal);
    bundle.putString("lang", Language);

    final Intent i2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MainView.class);
    i2.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    TabSpec spec2 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.deals));
    spec2.setContent(i2);
    spec2.setIndicator(createTabView(getApplicationContext(), myDrawable,
            getString(R.string.deals)));

    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabclick3);
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("lang", Language);

    final Intent i3 = new Intent().setClass(this, FavoriteView.class);
    i3.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    TabSpec spec3 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.favorite));
    spec3.setContent(i3);
    spec3.setIndicator(createTabView(getApplicationContext(), myDrawable,
            getString(R.string.favorite)));

    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabclick4);
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("lang", Language);

    final Intent i4 = new Intent().setClass(this, Search.class);
    i4.putExtra("bundle", bundle);

    TabSpec spec4 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.search));
    spec4.setContent(i4);
    spec4.setIndicator(createTabView(getApplicationContext(), myDrawable,
            getString(R.string.search)));

    myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabclick5);
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("lang", Language);

    final Intent i5 = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingView.class);
    i5.putExtra("bundle", bundle);

    TabSpec spec5 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.setting));
    spec5.setContent(i5);
    spec5.setIndicator(createTabView(getApplicationContext(), myDrawable,
            getString(R.string.setting)));

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int selectedTab = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            if (selectedTab == 0) {
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close);
                linkName = getString(R.string.featured);
            }
            if (selectedTab == 1) {
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_action_search);
                linkName = getString(R.string.deals);
            }
            if (selectedTab == 2) {
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting);
                linkName = getString(R.string.favorite);
            }
            if (selectedTab == 3) {
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting);
                linkName = getString(R.string.search);
            }
            if (selectedTab == 4) {
                myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting);
                linkName = getString(R.string.setting);
            }

            Log.d("SELECTED", "" + selectedTab);
        }
    });

    mTabHost.addTab(spec1);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec2);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec3);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec4);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec5);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onActivityResult(int, int,
 * android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    // AddDeal deal = new AddDeal();
    if (addDealInterface != null)
        addDealInterface.onRespondedResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    // Toast.makeText(this, "I am called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Creates the tab view.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param drawable
 *            the drawable
 * @param text
 *            the text
 * @return the view
 */
public static View createTabView(Context context, Drawable drawable,
        String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_main_bg,
            null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTabTag);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTabTag);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    return view;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    mTabHost = null;

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onBackPressed()
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    activeFragment.onBackPressed();
}

// method for TabFragment to call when the user navigates out of the app
/**
 * Close.
 */
public void close() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Comment: `TabHost` has **not** been `deprecated`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html